# How to fix "Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created model which name is `project`

> php artisan make:model project

and then using `php artisan tinker` tried to add a record into it.

In command line when I run:

> ```
> $project = new App\project;
> $project->title='My first project';
>  $project->save();
> ```

It shows this error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'field list' (SQL:
>   insert into `projects` (`title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (My first project, 2019-01-11 06:46:09, 2019-01-11 06:46:09))'

It doesn't perform `$project->save();` and gives this error. Please help.

Comment: show the complete code in command line tinker

Comment: Please can you add the code for the model and the migration to your question.

Comment: @InzamamIdrees Added after edit.

Comment: Please try $project = new App\project; (small 'p' in project)

Comment: if you create model in lowercase 'project', so why you can access uppercase in tinker......  $project = new App\Project;?

Comment: Still doesn't solve it. I repeated the process with 'project'.

Comment: Can you share what `DESCRIBE projects` shows in MySQL console?

Comment: That's an odd thing to get from a `DESCRIBE` command.

Comment: Hold on, I made a mistake, it returns "id", "created_at"," updated_at" fields.

Comment: Share you migration for the table 'projects'. It clearly says `title` column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try this:

```
 $project = new Project;

 $project->title = $request->title;

 $project->save(); // it will INSERT a new record
```

**Updated Answer**

```
$project = new App\Project;
$project->title='My first project';
 $project->save();
```

Comment: Sir, that is exactly what I wrote, still gives me that error.

Comment: @indiadevelops: Please check you have `title` field in your project table and make sure your table name is `project` ?

Comment: My table name is *projects* and it does not have a *title* field.

Comment: @indiadevelops: Oh that is the problem because you store your value in `title` field so you getting error

Comment: @indiadevelops: Please add `title` field in your `projects` table or store value in correct field

Comment: @indiadevelops check my answer, already include an edit to add only `title` column. This will perform a different migration than before

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal adding 'title' fixed the error. Thankyou. :)

Answer (score 2):

### No migration performed

```
php artisan make:model project
```

This is the fault which I believe you do not have a migration file created (refer to `Future Reference` section below why I said so), since the error stated that the column is not found.

To better solve this, I suggest you create a migration file as follow:

```
php artisan make:migration create_projects_table
```

You can see inside `database/migrations`, there is a new file with the name `2019_01_11_153037_create_projects_table` something. The time and date is different from yours, but the main focus is 'create_projects_table'

Inside the migration file, you can see there's `up()` function. Copy this code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, perform a migration, and you should see a migrated success message.

```
php artisan migrate
```

### Future reference

In the future, to save time, you can create a model together with its migration, as follow:

```
php artisan make:model Project -m
```

Notice the `-m` tag, which creates a migration file for you. Afterwards, proceed with editing the migration file (e.g., add columns to it as demonstrated previously).

Learn more about Laravel's migration here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

One additional notes, check out Laravel's convention on Eloquent Model so that Laravel can perform it's magic:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Your `project` model should properly be `Project`

### Edit

If you have performed a migration somehow before, then run a different migration (there's no limit to how much you can make migration).

```
php artisan make:migration add_column_title_to_projects_table
```

And there's a new migration file created. Inside the `up()` function, add this code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('title');
    });
}
```

Finally, perform `php artisan migrate`

Comment: I did repeat all steps and checked if I didn't miss any, but it still shows me the same error.

Comment: Have you try creating a different model? Or I suggest you manually create a 'title' column from the database, and redo the insertion steps again. Because seeing from the DESCRIBE above, the `title` is missing, that is why I propose the migration solution.

Comment: Is there any error when you run the migration? Maybe you can include only this column instead of `id` and `timestamp`: `$table->string('title')`

I will update the answer